# Issues getting kerberos/Windows AD login work for a web service

Tags: nginx, active-directory, kerberos, gssapi

I have been struggling with this for quite a while now, and I can't get it to work.

Here is the setup:
I have a nginx webserver serving a django app at `mywebapp.k8s.dal1.mycompany.io`

It has the SPNEGO plugin compiled in and I have the following endpoint in my config:

```
location /ad-login {
    uwsgi_pass django;
    include /usr/lib/mycompany/lib/wsgi/uwsgi_params;
    auth_gss on;
    auth_gss_realm BURNERDEV1.DAL1.MYCOMPANY.IO;
    auth_gss_service_name HTTP/mywebapp.k8s.dal1.mycompany.io;
    auth_gss_allow_basic_fallback off;
}
```

My AD Domain controller is at burnerdev1.dal1.mycompany.io and I have the following users configured:

```
rep_movsd
portal
```

I run the following commands on the DC server in an Admin prompt:

```
ktpass -out krb5.keytab -mapUser portal@BURNERDEV1.DAL1.MYCOMPANY.IO +rndPass -mapOp set +DumpSalt -crypto AES256-SHA1 -ptype KRB5_NT_PRINCIPAL -princ HTTP/mywebapp.k8s.dal1.mycompany.io@BURNERDEV1.DAL1.MYCOMPANY.IO
setspn -A HTTP/mywebapp.k8s.dal1.mycompany.io@BURNERDEV1.DAL1.MYCOMPANY.IO portal


C:\Users\myself\Documents\keytab>ktpass -out krb5.keytab -mapUser portal@BURNERDEV1.DAL1.MYCOMPANY.IO +rndPass -mapOp set +DumpSalt -crypto AES256-SHA1 -ptype KRB5_NT_PRINCIPAL -princ HTTP/mywebapp.k8s.dal1.mycompany.io@BURNERDEV1.DAL1.MYCOMPANY.IO

Targeting domain controller: dal1devdc1.burnerdev1.dal1.mycompany.io
Using legacy password setting method
Failed to set property 'servicePrincipalName' to 'HTTP/mywebapp.k8s.dal1.mycompany.io' on Dn 'CN=portal,CN=Users,DC=burnerdev1,DC=dal1,
DC=mycompany,DC=io': 0x13.
WARNING: Unable to set SPN mapping data.
If portal already has an SPN mapping installed for HTTP/mywebapp.k8s.dal1.mycompany.io, this is no cause for concern.
Building salt with principalname HTTP/mywebapp.k8s.dal1.mycompany.io and domain BURNERDEV1.DAL1.MYCOMPANY.IO (encryption type 18)...
Hashing password with salt "BURNERDEV1.DAL1.MYCOMPANY.IOHTTPmywebapp.k8s.dal1.mycompany.io".
Key created.
Output keytab to krb5.keytab:
Keytab version: 0x502
keysize 110 HTTP/mywebapp.k8s.dal1.mycompany.io@BURNERDEV1.DAL1.MYCOMPANY.IO ptype 1 (KRB5_NT_PRINCIPAL) vno 3 etype 0x12 (AES256-SHA1) k
eylength 32 (0x632d9ca3356374e9de490ec2f7718f9fb652b20da40bd212a808db4c46a72bc5)

C:\Users\myself\Documents\keytab>setspn -A HTTP/mywebapp.k8s.dal1.mycompany.io@BURNERDEV1.DAL1.MYCOMPANY.IO portal
Checking domain DC=burnerdev1,DC=dal1,DC=mycompany,DC=io

Registering ServicePrincipalNames for CN=portal,CN=Users,DC=burnerdev1,DC=dal1,DC=mycompany,DC=io
        HTTP/mywebapp.k8s.dal1.mycompany.io@BURNERDEV1.DAL1.MYCOMPANY.IO
Updated object

C:\Users\myself\Documents\keytab>
```

Now in the "Active Directory Users and Computers" section, I rightclicked the user and selected "Properties"
Then on the "Delegation" tab I set "Trust this user for delegation to any service (Kerberos only)"

Next I copy the krb5.keytab file to my webserver and restart the nginx container

On the Windows workstation which is part of the domain, I log on as rep_movsd - when I run klist:

```
C:\Users\rep_movsd>klist

Current LogonId is 0:0x208d7

Cached Tickets: (2)

#0>     Client: rep_movsd @ BURNERDEV1.DAL1.MYCOMPANY.IO
        Server: krbtgt/BURNERDEV1.DAL1.MYCOMPANY.IO @ BURNERDEV1.DAL1.MYCOMPANY.IO
        KerbTicket Encryption Type: AES-256-CTS-HMAC-SHA1-96
        Ticket Flags 0x40e10000 -> forwardable renewable initial pre_authent name_canonicalize
        Start Time: 7/16/2020 2:05:51 (local)
        End Time:   7/16/2020 12:05:51 (local)
        Renew Time: 7/23/2020 2:05:51 (local)
        Session Key Type: AES-256-CTS-HMAC-SHA1-96


#1>     Client: rep_movsd @ BURNERDEV1.DAL1.MYCOMPANY.IO
        Server: HTTP/mywebapp.k8s.dal1.mycompany.io @ BURNERDEV1.DAL1.MYCOMPANY.IO
        KerbTicket Encryption Type: AES-256-CTS-HMAC-SHA1-96
        Ticket Flags 0x40a10000 -> forwardable renewable pre_authent name_canonicalize
        Start Time: 7/16/2020 2:06:01 (local)
        End Time:   7/16/2020 12:05:51 (local)
        Renew Time: 7/23/2020 2:05:51 (local)
        Session Key Type: AES-256-CTS-HMAC-SHA1-96
```

I setup Firefox to do SPENGO authentication
Then I hit mywebapp.k8s.dal1.mycompany.io/ad-login and I get a `403 Forbidden` error

The nginx server debug log shows:

```
[debug] 16#16: *195 Client sent a reasonable Negotiate header 
[debug] 16#16: *195 GSSAPI authorizing 
[debug] 16#16: *195 Use keytab /etc/krb5.keytab 
[debug] 16#16: *195 Using service principal: HTTP/mywebapp.k8s.dal1.mycompany.io@BURNERDEV1.DAL1.MYCOMPANY.IO 
[debug] 16#16: *195 my_gss_name HTTP/mywebapp.k8s.dal1.mycompany.io@BURNERDEV1.DAL1.MYCOMPANY.IO 
[debug] 16#16: *195 gss_accept_sec_context() failed: Cannot decrypt ticket for HTTP/mywebapp.k8s.dal1.mycompany.io@BURNERDEV1.DAL1.MYCOMPANY.IO using keytab key for HTTP/mywebapp.k8s.dal1.mycompany.io@BURNERDEV1.DAL1.MYCOMPANY.IO: 
[debug] 16#16: *195 GSSAPI failed 
[debug] 16#16: *195 http finalize request: 403, "/ad-login?" a:1, c:1 
[debug] 16#16: *195 http special response: 403, "/ad-login?" 
[debug] 16#16: *195 http set discard body 
[debug] 16#16: *195 charset: "" > "utf-8" 
[debug] 16#16: *195 HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
```

BTW while messing around earlier - I found that if I had set a fixed password for the "portal" user with ktpass and logged in as that account on the workstation, the login would succeed.
I was under the mistaken impression that I'd need to create a new keytab for every user and combine all of them.

Any help is greatly appreciated - I read so many conflicting docs its only confused me further and I've been losing sleep over this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I see one explicit problem when the keytab was created:  "Failed to set property 'servicePrincipalName' to 'HTTP/mywebapp.k8s.dal1.mycompany.io' on Dn 'CN=portal,CN=Users,DC=burnerdev1,DC=dal1,
DC=mycompany,DC=io': 0x13."   Glad you saved the output.

Comment: Are the domain controller, web app, and client all running on the *same* machine, or are they running in separate machines (physical or virtual)?  Your testing would be better off if they were kept separate.

Comment: That error you see happened because I ran the command a second time - by which time the spn was already set, so it failed to.

As for the machines - this is an actual internal development network with a AD server, and my local machine has a Windows VM and the web server is yet another cluster of machines.

Comment: Let me ask you a question....

Tell me if I understood it correctly....

A service account (here portal) gets associated with a principalname in the keytab.

Keytab has some hash of the service accounts password.

The GSS authentication expects a similar hashed value.

How can this work unless the user rep_movsd has the service accounts credentials somehow?

When I experimented on a linux system, I just added multiple keytabs with ktutil - each one was a user and their password. 
Each local user could kinit and then get access.

I dont get the Windows logic!!

Comment: I think I know what's wrong.  I will take a stab at an answer and answer this in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've read your problem statement carefully, and I think if you follow the steps I wrote below the issue will be solved.

1. On the DC server where you are creating the keytab, (1) UAC must be temporarily disabled.  (2) The user creating the keytab must be a member of the Domain Admins group.
2. Ensure the SPN is not a duplicate, then remove the SPN from the Active Directory user account *portal*.  This **must** be done before creating a new keytab using the same SPN against the same account.  The below command is a one-liner, word-wrapping makes it look like two lines.

*setspn -d HTTP/mywebapp.k8s.dal1.mycompany.io@BURNERDEV1.DAL1.MYCOMPANY.IO portal*

3. Re-create the keytab again exactly as you did before.
4. You do not need to run the command `setspn -A HTTP/mywebapp.k8s.dal1.mycompany.io@BURNERDEV1.DAL1.MYCOMPANY.IO portal` because SPN was already set on the Active Directory user account by the ktpass command in step 3.
5. Replace the old keytab with the new keytab.
6. Restart the nginx webserver service.
7. Clear browser cache AND clear Kerberos case (*klist purge*).
8. Try it again.

You must do all these steps including the final step 7.  Do not skip any.

You service account is named *portal*.  A hash of this password is stored in both Active Directory and the keytab.  Same hash is in both locations.  The keytab on the nginix server is utilized to decrypt the inbound Kerberos service tickets to determine who the user is attempting to access the web app.  More specifically, the GSS authentication does all the work, *it* uses the keytab to un-scramble the encrypted service tickets.  The user rep_movsd does *not* have the service account credentials.  It is part of the Active Directory domain, and when accessing the nginix web server, it gets it's own Kerberos service ticket and its identity is proven to the web server by simply being in possession of a service ticket that is decrypted by the keytab.  If it wasn't part of the BURNERDEV1.DAL1.MYCOMPANY.IO domain, or had an expired password, or was a disabled account, it would not be able to get a service ticket and thus not prove its identity and fail authentication.

If you have time, please see my TechNet Wiki [article](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/36470.active-directory-using-kerberos-keytabs-to-integrate-non-windows-systems.aspx) on keytab creation and the logic behind it to help you better understand this complex subject.

Comment: Thanks for your response...
I recreated the service user and the end user account to be sure I start from a clean state.

1) My account is a full admin, I disabled UAC via the GUI (set the slider all the way down)

2) setspn -L portal shows
Registered ServicePrincipalNames for CN=portal,CN=Users,DC=burnerdev1,DC=dal1,DC=mycompany,DC=io:

3) Create keytab fails again with:
Failed to set property 'servicePrincipalName' to 'HTTP/mywebapp.k8s.dal1.mycompany.io' on Dn 'CN=portal,CN=Users,DC=burnerd
ev1,DC=dal1,DC=mycompany,DC=io': 0x13.
WARNING: Unable to set SPN mapping data.

Comment: The keytab gets generated, its exactly the same as I had before and login fails.


In the AD management console, the attribute "servicePrincipalName" does exist as a blank entry - I tried manually changing that - no use.


I used setspn to add it - still no use


I tried the same process you recommended with the service account as member of "Managed service accounts" - still the same thing.

Comment: I am pretty sure the webserver end is working, because if I login as "portal" itself from the client machine, the authentication succeeds.

I didn't realize you were the author of that article - its where I got my ktpass command from in the first place!

Can I contact you directly for help over some form of chat or email?

Comment: The error indicates lack of permission to update the AD user account.  You said you were a full admin, did that mean Domain Admin?  Please open CMD.exe with your Domain Admin credentials.

Comment: Responding to you other comment here...sure, you can message me at  LinkedIn (www.linkedin.com/in/todd-heron-1aba7b105) and we can figure something out.

Comment: I edited step #2, which may be the issue here.  It *must* always be done before step 3.

Comment: So the issue turned out to be that another earlier test account I had made was already assigned that SPN, so it failed to assign to this one.

I found a Powershell script that could list all SPNs of all users and got rid of that one.
Then it worked fine!

Thanks again for your help

Comment: Ah, yes.  I edited my article to capture this scenario.

Comment: Don't forget to re-enable UAC